# Connecting 14.04 to Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, login, authentication

I have a machine with 14.04 and a Windows 8.1.  They are connected to a gigabit router.  Both are connected to a VPN.  The Windows machine is able to see the Linux machine and copy files to it.

The Linux machine can see the Windows machine, but when I try to access it, it pops the password question.  I enter the Windows credentials, a hotmail address and the password for the Windows computer, but it won't authenticate.

This is my first Linux machine and I can't find the answer.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Drew

Answer (score 0):

I think this sounds like a windows issue, since connecting to your ubuntu/linux computer seems to work.

Have you tried making a new local user (not an online/hotmail user) on the windows computer, and then use the new user & password to connect from the ubuntu/linux to windows?

I'm suspecting that it could be the windows hotmail address online user that's causing problems, and it would probably be more secure to have a separate user for remote logins too (though maybe not as convenient), it would be great to limit that new user's access to only it's own home & shared directory, and limit running programs, but I don't know if/how windows can do that.

Comment: Yes, I tried making a local user with the same result.  I just pulled out my laptop which is Windows 7 and it worked immediately, so it must be something in 8.1 that I am not doing right.

Comment: Definitely something different from windows 7 to 8.1, if there's nothing in windows' own help, maybe an "allow remote user login" or similar, then I'm out of ideas, I'd try web searches like login fails windows 8.1 but works windows 7 ?